# Div that adjusts width to fill space next to image of undefined size

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a Div that holds head shot images with a set height and undefined width.  I would like to display a logo image to the left of head shot image.  I would like the logo (Techno Lock Image) to fill the remaining width and not go behind the Name Bar Div.  If the head shots URL breaks I am using JavaScript to display no image.  If the head shot image is broken the logo should fill the entire div.

[My JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/220af6qt/)

HTML:

```
<div class="image-holder">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://cdn.photographyproject.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/corporate-headshot.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="caption">
    <a href="http://google.com">John Smith</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image-holder">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://www.playbillsvspayingbills.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/ben-whitehair-military-headshot.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="caption">
    <a href="http://google.com">Greg Hampton</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image-holder">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="Error.src" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
  </div>
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="caption">
    <a href="http://google.com">Candice Cade</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-holder {
  width: 300px;
  height: 164px;
  position: relative;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: auto;
  height: 164px;
  //max-height: 164px;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 30;
  right: 0px;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  background-image: url("https://www.callcentrehelper.com/images/stories/2010/2016/06/cyber-security-blue-image-760-300x164.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 164px;
}

.caption {
  background-color: rgb(43, 69, 83);
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 43px;
  left: 0px;
  line-height: 18.2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 40;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

a {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: none;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: 0px;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  background-repeat-x: ;
  background-repeat-y: ;
  background-size: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: auto;
  display: inline;
  font-family: HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: just put the logo and the shot image in a wrapper, that you give a display:flex. the logo should become this css property: flex-grow: 1;

Comment: If you want the headshot but not the logo to go behind the text bar and everything is absolutely positioned you are most likely going to need another wrapping div in there around the logo with the height set.  However if you can I would suggest that flexbox might be a good solution to this layout!

Comment: If you want the logo image to fill the remaining space, do you mean you want it to scale? I can imagine for the first example in your design, the logo would be squished and progressively get less squished as the headshot width becomes less.

Comment: @MarouenMhiri can you mark it up in JSFiddle I tried that but it didn't have an effect. https://jsfiddle.net/220af6qt/1/

Comment: @Illdapt yes I want it to scale.  but keep its aspect ratio

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/220af6qt/3/

Comment: @Nickfmc Thats perfect!.. but can the headshot picture be on the right?

Comment: @Nickfmc I answered with your suggestion.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this based on Nickfmc's JSFiddle using Display: Flex on the wrapper and flex:1 on the logo div.

[Nicks JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/220af6qt/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="image-holder">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://cdn.photographyproject.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/corporate-headshot.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="caption">
    <a href="http://google.com">John Smith</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image-holder">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://www.playbillsvspayingbills.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/ben-whitehair-military-headshot.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="caption">
    <a href="http://google.com">Greg Hampton</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image-holder">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="front">
    <img src="Error.src" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
  </div>
  <div class="caption">
    <a href="http://google.com">Candice Cade</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-holder {
  width: 300px;
  height: 164px;
  position: relative;
  Display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: auto;
  height: 164px;
  //max-height: 164px;
}

.front {
  z-index: 30;
  left: 0px;
}

.back {
  z-index: 20;
  background-image: url("https://www.callcentrehelper.com/images/stories/2010/2016/06/cyber-security-blue-image-760-300x164.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 164px;
  flex: 1;
}

.caption {
  background-color: rgb(43, 69, 83);
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 43px;
  left: 0px;
  line-height: 18.2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 40;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

a {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: none;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: 0px;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  background-repeat-x: ;
  background-repeat-y: ;
  background-size: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: auto;
  display: inline;
  font-family: HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```